# Inserting a range into the last column of used data in a sheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, range

I have an array of doubles that I am trying to write to a certain sheet in excel.

The thing is this sheet already has data in it. There are plenty of code snippets out there that shows me how to find the last column of used data and returns the NUMBER of the column. But I am trying to write the data in my array using the range function which needs a letter as a string. Is there a better method to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim lCol As Integer
        With GlobVars.Wksht
            lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column
        End With
        lCol += 1
        GlobVars.Wksht.Range("I need something in these parentheses that will relate the lcol value and whatever row I want to put it in").Value = deltaxyarr 'copies the deltaxyarr as a range into the current active worksheet (data reduction)
```

Comment: Is this really VB.NET? A .NET `Long` seems wrong

Comment: I chose long as my data type because it is a decimal type number. I change the data type of my array that I will be copying into excel, but I am truly more interested in the syntax of how to write to a range in the next unused column of data @Plutonix

Edit: I can change it to As Decimal but that really wouldn't change anything that I am asking about would it? :)

Comment: A long is an integral type - no decimals.  > 9,000,000,000,000,000,000 seems much larger than the column count could ever be

Comment: @Plutonix I think I see the confusion here. my lcol number is a long type. You're right that doesn't need to be a long it should just be an integer. I do have an array of long type, but my original point still stands XD I edited my original post so my index for the last column used is in integer.

Comment: Before answering you, is it VBA code or VB.NET? I guess it's VBA because Range property in VB.NET has different notation from VBA's one.

Comment: You can't use Cells(row, column).Address to return the string?

Comment: @JohnyL I am using vb.net. Are you sure my range is not properly working in vb.net? I am using a similar line of code somewhere else in my program

Comment: @QHarr Thank you! I think I am able to work with something using the Cells.Address. I will update my post if/when I get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

For transferring array to worksheet, you need to have Range's size the same as array's size. In order to do it, you can use handy Resize property. Here's how things work:

```
Sub TransferArray()

    Dim arr As Variant

    'Copy range into array.
    'This array is 1) always 2-dimensional and 2) its lower bound is always 1.
    arr = Range("A1:F10")

    'To transer array, the receiving range should accomodate array fully.
    'To do it, we can use Resize property.
    'This means, all we need is to choose top left cell of our receiving range.
    'Here K1 cell is this very cell.
    'The RowSize argument means how many rows we should expand down,
    'and ColumnSize - how many column we should expand right.
    'Apparently, these numbers are upper bound of 1-st dimension
    'and upper bound of 2-nd dimension, respectively.
    Range("K1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi JohnyL thanks for the reply. I am trying to locate the exact location of where to put the array on the sheet. For example lets say my data (which will always be a 5x3 array) in excel spans a distance from A1:C5. I have another array that I want to put right next the first data set starting at D1, but I need a line of code that will find that next unused column. I then need a line of code that will put that unused column in such a way this line of code will work:



{Range("starting cell D1 here").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr}

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to Qharr I was able to get some code working using the Cells.Address member. Here's my code snippet I found to be working:

```
            lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column

            lCol += 1
            GlobVars.Wksht.Range(GlobVars.Wksht.Cells(1, lCol).Address).Resize(UBound(deltaxyarr, 1), UBound(deltaxyarr, 2)).Value = deltaxyarr
```